# usb mouse not working in fedora 24

Tags: usb, mouse, fedora

I had recently upgraded to fedora 24 from 23, but in 24 as soon as i log into my account my usb mouse stops working.Though i can use my trackpad perfectly.

Here is what running lsusb command shows(think it might help).

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:648d Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 15d9:0a4c Trust International B.V. USB+PS/2 Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you solve it?

Comment: @MichaelClerx No, but i have found out a work around for it. All i do is as soon as the mouse stops working i close my laptop lid and let it go in sleep mode for 2-3 seconds and then start my laptop again and it starts working. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @ShahbajSayyad I have the same mouse (according to lsusb) and the same problem in a freshly installed Fedora 25. Going into standby helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was solved when I changed my USB mouse.